# I'm trying to write a function that multiply all elements from a vector in R

Tags: r

What it should do is take a vector like `w = c(w1,w2,w3)` and what it does is `w1*w2`, `w1*w3` and `w2*w3`. I'm looking for a formula that is general enough to take 10 weights or more.

```
multelem <- function(x){
+     x1 <- numeric(0)
+     for(i in x){
+         x1 <- x[i]*x[i+1]  
+     }
+     print(x1)
+ }
```

The idea was to multiple the weights next to each other. If this functioned worked I would have added a line like `x2 <- x[i]*x[i+2]` and so until `length(w)`. Unfortunately for me, I'm having trouble making this function well. I think I have the intuition right, but the execution is not working. Please share any ideas, or if there's a package that already solved this, please let me know.

Thanks in advance

Comment: in your example, if you want to multiply "the weights next to each other", why do you need `w1*w3` ? `w1` and `w3` are not adjacent.

Comment: you can check out `expand.grid` function too.

Answer (score 2):

Along the lines of thelatemail anwser.

```
x=c(1,2,3,4)
combn(x, 2, FUN = function(x) x[1]*x[2])
```

Comment: Or `combn(x, 2, FUN = prod)`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
multelem <- function(x){
  x1 <- numeric(0)
       for(i in 1:(length(x)-1)){
         x1[i] <- x[i]*x[i+1]  
       }
  print(x1)}
```

Since you were using (i in x), it was taking first number in an vector as i and it could not find an number for x[i+1].

Comment: how does this do pairwise? i.e x[1] * x[3] which is needed by OP?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
multelem <- function(x){
c <- 1
for(i in x){
  c = 1+c
  x1 <- i*x[c] 
  print(x1)
}
}

x <- c(1,3,5,7,9)
multelem(x)
```